# Cropping image in Django causes substantial memory increase

Tags: django, python-imaging-library, webfaction

I've recently run into a problem with my Django project and memory usage on WebFaction.

Here is the two processes running in memory for this project on webfaction:

```
30396  4-20:20:00 13486 
30404  4-20:20:00 13487
```

After the view is run one of the processes will increase substantially:

```
69720  4-20:20:22 13486 
30404  4-20:20:22 13487
```

As you can see the first process more than doubled in memory usage!  As this function will be used often I need to figure out what is happening.  I believe I've narrowed it down to the following view (it's a 3 step process to upload an image, add details, crop a thumbnail).

Here is the view below.  It gets a photo object, loads the image from the file, gets the box coordinates that the user has submitted and then creates a 200,200 sized image.  This newly created image is written back to the disk with a .thumbnail in the filename and the photo object is saved.

```
@login_required
def upload3(request, photo_pk):
    photo = get_object_or_404(Photo, pk=photo_pk, user=request.user)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = upload3Form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            im = Image.open(photo.image.path)
            try:
                box =(form.cleaned_data['x1'],form.cleaned_data['y1'],form.cleaned_data['x2'],form.cleaned_data['y2'])
            except:
                box = ('0','0','1000','1000')
            cropped = im.crop(box)
            cropped.thumbnail((200,200),Image.ANTIALIAS)
            result = os.path.splitext(photo.image.path)
            cropped.save(result[0] + '.thumbnail' + result[1])
            photo.status = 3
            photo.save()
```

Any ideas of what I may be doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

`Update 1`:  Images used for testing are all Jpeg and have dimensions around 3600 x 2700 and are around 2 MB per image.

Comment: Have you narrowed down which operation in the view causes the memory use to increase? What happens if the view is invoked multiple times?

Comment: No I have not, as I am not able to do as much debugging on a live server (such as pdb).  It doesn't seem to happen every time the view is invoked, but most times.  (After I uploaded about couple of images a few weeks back the memory usage was above 112 mb on one process).

Comment: Would you mind updating your question with the typical image size and format?

Comment: @PauloScardine I've updated the original question with that info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of digging and dead-ends I tried something not suggested anywhere and it worked.

On each object that contained an image object used in PIL I had to delete the object once I was done with it.   So for example:

```
im = Image.open(photo.image.path)
try:
    box  =(form.cleaned_data['x1'],form.cleaned_data['y1'],form.cleaned_data['x2'],form.cleaned_data['y2'])
except:
    box = ('0','0','1000','1000')
cropped = im.crop(box)
newimage = cropped.resize((form.cleaned_data['dw'],form.cleaned_data['dh']),Image.ANTIALIAS)
del im
del cropped
```

So once I'm done with the object I call del on that item.  It seems to have fixed the problem.  I no longer have memory increases and I couldn't be happier.

Comment: it would be a lot nicer of you to update your question with the solution you found instead of answering your own question and taking back the acceptance from my answer.

Comment: I feel that mine was the more complete answer and when people come to a question they look more for the green checkbox than an update to the original question.  I still gave you bounty...

Answer (score 2):

The 2M figure is for a compressed JPEG image, but uncompressed, 3600 x 2700 truecolor will be about 38M (9,720,000 pixels at 4B per pixel), close to the memory usage increase you are experiencing.

This is a known problem with PIL, I can produce a pixel bomb by sending you a 40000x40000 pixel black picture as a png. Always check the resolution before loading (or protect the code with a try/except block handling OutOfMemory). See if using im.tile attribute to process the image chunk by chunk gives you a lower memory footprint.

May be worth checking:

- [django-image-cropping](https://pypi.org/project/django-image-cropping/)
- [sorl-thumbnail](https://web.archive.org/web/20210731145453/http://thumbnail.sorl.net/)

Some alternatives that are said to better handle memory when dealing with larger images:

- [GDAL](https://gdal.org/) (Geospatial Data Abstraction Library)
- [OIIO](https://openimageio.org/) (OpenImageIO)
- [Mahotas](https://pythonhosted.org/mahotas/index.html) (NumPy)

[ update ]

> Do you know if there's a way in PIL to release the objects from memory? Because in theory that would be best for this view as I need it to work like it does, but just handle the image better.

- In order to avoid memory spikes you can detect huge images and try to process them in chunks using `im.tile` instead of `im.crop` (unfortunatelly operating at a lower level).
- You can delete the intermediate image objects as soon as possible in order to get shorter spikes (using the [gc module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html) you can force the garbage collector to cleanup).

Comment: Oh that makes sense I would have never thought about that the pictures are compressed.  I've started looking more into what you suggested and I'll see if they work.  Do you know if there's a way in PIL to release the objects from memory?  Because in theory that would be best for this view as I need it to work like it does, but just handle the image better.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize you had updated your answer.  Thank you for your answer as you provided insight into what was causing the memory spike.  (Which is what my question was).  I'm going to talk to WebFaction to see if they have any ideas as I have a decent idea of a workaround that won't require hours of work on my part.